# NSMenuItem setting state not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I have a document based app in Swift 1.2. I want to have programmatically generated `NSMenuItem`'s that have an action to the current NSDocument, and then have that selection get checked. Here's what I have so far:

**AppDelegate**

```
// generate items
for thing in thingArray {
    var newThing = NSMenuItem(title:name, action: Selector("myMethod:"), keyEquivalent: "")
    newThing.enabled = true
    submenu.addItem(newThing)
}
```

**MyDocument**

```
// getting current AppDelegate
let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

// called by user selected menu item
@IBAction func myMethod(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let parent = sender.parentItem!

    // iterate through all Items to setState: NSOffState

    for item in parent.submenu!.itemArray as! [NSMenuItem] {
        if workspace?.name == item.title {
            item.state = NSOnState     
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I know that all the code up to the `item.state` is working. I put print logs to test it. But what happens is usually the menu item doesn't get checked, but occasionally it does.

My best guess is that the menu isn't refreshing but I am not sure how to do it.  Could it also be that the `NSMenuItem`'s action is being sent through the First Responder chain? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An more efficient way to do that is to create an instance variable `currentIndex` holding the index of the current menu item. When the function `myMethod` is called, set the state of the menu item at `currentIndex` to `NSOffState` and the state of `sender` to `NSOnState`. Then set `currentIndex` to the index of `sender`. That avoids the repeat loop.

Comment: Where do you uncheck the menu item?

Comment: @vadian That was a great idea (and I will do it regardless), but I got the same behavior.

Comment: @Willeke I left it out of the code posted, but I will edit my original post to show when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I see what was happening. The part in AppDelegate that is creating the menu items is called every 3 seconds (part of an API I'm using). The problem was that the menu items are being recreated, so the states I was setting were not always the current `NSMenuItem`'s that were in the menu.

I found out that I could use `validateMenuItem` in the NSDocument to update each menu item that matched my criteria.

```
override func validateMenuItem(menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
    menuItem.state = workspaceIndex == menuItem.tag ? NSOnState : NSOffState
    return true
}
```